# Спрятать один елемент и показать второй после события

Tags: javascript, html

Есть простой генератор ([ссылка на codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/MJBNBW)).
Как после алерта спрятать кнопку "ask" и показать "new"?

```js
function GetValue()
    {
        var myarray = new Array("word1","word2","word3");
        var random = myarray[Math.floor(Math.random() * myarray.length)];
       document.getElementById("message").innerHTML=random;
    };
    //rand array element
    
    var clicks = 0;
    function onClick() {
        clicks += 1;
        document.getElementById("clicks").innerHTML = clicks;
      printMessage(document.getElementById("message").innerHTML,clicks);
    };
    //count clicks
    
    function printMessage(random, clicks) {
      if (random === "word1") {
        document.getElementById("alert").innerHTML =
        "wow, after " + clicks + " clicks";
      }
    }
    //display "you get word1 after _ clicks"
    
    function myFunction() {
        location.reload();
    }
    //reload
```

```html
<body>
  <textarea id="message" rows="1"></textarea>
  <input type="button" id="btnSearch" value="ask" onclick="GetValue();onClick()" />


<p>attempts: <a id="clicks">0</a></p>

<p id="alert"></p>

<button id="reload" onclick="myFunction()">new</button>
```

Comment: Не вижу в коде ни одной кнопки

Comment: Извините, забыл добавить html. Но я оставил ссылку на codepen

Comment: if (alert==true)
  {
  спрятать одну кнопку; показать другую кнопку
  }
я правильно думаю?

Comment: Вам нужно при выполнении условия `if (random === "word1")` спрятать одну кнопку и показать другую. Я правильно понял? И сейчас у Вас отображаются обе кнопки - это так и задумано?

Comment: Да, Вы правильно поняли! Сейчас отображаются обе, но одну я изначально спрятал через display:none (в codepen уже изменил)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну вот так

```js
function GetValue() {
  var myarray = new Array("word1", "word2", "word3");
  var random = myarray[Math.floor(Math.random() * myarray.length)];
  document.getElementById("message").innerHTML = random;
};
//rand array element

var clicks = 0;

function onClick() {
  clicks += 1;
  document.getElementById("clicks").innerHTML = clicks;
  printMessage(document.getElementById("message").innerHTML, clicks);
};
//count clicks

function printMessage(random, clicks) {
  if (random === "word1") {
    document.getElementById("alert").innerHTML =
      "wow, after " + clicks + " clicks";
    document.getElementById("btnSearch").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("reload").style.display = "block";
  }
};
//display "you get word1 after _ clicks"


function myFunction() {
  location.reload();
};
//reload
```

```css
#reload {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<textarea id="message" rows="1"></textarea>
<input type="button" id="btnSearch" value="ask" onclick="GetValue();onClick()" />

<p>attempts: <span id="clicks">0</span>
</p>

<p id="alert"></p>

<button id="reload" onclick="myFunction()">new</button>
```